# can i Programatically Change Sharepoint OOB document approval workflow

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I have document library where I am using the Out-Of-the box document approval workflow.

I need to allow users to delegate their tasks to another person during a certain period. This delegation is on workflow level not on item level. something that can be used for example where someone will be out of the office for a long period and needs to assign a delegate to approve documents.

I was thinking of changing the list of approvers programatically to allow someone to use a custom form to enable that delegation.

Can this be done? is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to actually create your own workflow. Much better than trying to hack the OOB workflow.  In my experience messing with a running workflow is never good and prone to complications / failures.

If you are wary of/restricted building workflows with VS then using a tool such as Nintex (Nintex.com) is a great option, I haved used it a few projects now.

Sorry I could'nt be more use.